# false-positive error using std::functional in vs2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, stdbind

I have implemented some test functionals yesterday and everything compiled and worked fine without errors. Today i came back to my PC and my `std::bind`'s are underlined red but compile without error. Seems like Intellisense and the compiler do not agree on the `std::bind` type. How can I fix this?

```
#include <functional>

class MyClass {
public:
    int doE() {
        return 0;
    }

    int doF() {
        return 1;
    }
};


void main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    std::function<int()> f = std::bind(&MyClass::doE, obj); // underlined red
    std::cout << f();
}
```

The error message is as follows:

> ```
> Error (active)
>     no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, int (MyClass::*)(), MyClass &>" to "std::function<int ()>" exists
>     functionals
>     c:\functionals\functionals\thirdFunctionOnObject.h
> ```

I do have the same error type (Intellisense saying there is an error, but it compiles just fine) in more sophisticated code, where I used `std::mem_fn().`

Comment: Intellisense can usually be safely ignored.  It's almost completely useless.

Comment: The Visual Studio IntelliSense parser is not the same as used by the Visual C++ compiler. IntelliSense can sometimes think that valid code is invalid and report it as an error.

Comment: Try using a lambda instead of `std::bind`, as there are very few reasons to use `std::bind` over lambda other than obscure breaks caused by `std::bind` quirks, complex and unreadable error messages from `std::bind` mistakes, and general masochism?

Comment: I reworked my code to use lambdas and it's great. Readability is improved and no more error messages. Thanks Yakk!

Comment: Well, what changed on your PC last night?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with VS 2015 C++, I hate it. Microsoft drives me crazy.

For now I am using a nasty work around by moving the code to a static function. In your case it will be similar to the following:

```
class MyClass {
    // other code

    int doE () {
        return 0;
    }

    static int statDoE(MyClass * myClass) {
        return myClass->doE();
    }

}
```